# Add JSF Message From Spring Bean

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security, message, facescontext

I'm having problem with adding message to `FacesContext` from Spring component. Here is the senario:

1. User logins from .xhtml page
2. Spring Security authorize user
3. If user success/failed, return message to the UI from Spring managed class (`AuthenticationFailureHandler`, `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`), which is primefaces.

I can't add message via:

```
@Component
public class LoginFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginFailureHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.info("Login failed: " + httpServletRequest.getParameter("j_username"), e);
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Login Error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/timsgui/login.jsf?error=1");
    }
}
```

Because this class is not in JSF lifecycle, `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` returns `null`. Here is my jsf page:

```
<body>

    <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true" life="3000" />

    <h:form name="login" action="../j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
        <h:panelGrid>
            <h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Username:"/>
            <p:inputText id="j_username"/>

            <h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password:"/>
            <p:password id="j_password"/>

            <!-- need CSRF protection which is enabled default after Spring 4-->
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Login" update="growl" type="submit"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

I tried to inject `FacesContext` into spring bean but it still returns `null`:

`@ManagedProperty("#{facesContext}")`

Is there anyway that i can inject current `FacesContext` to the Spring bean or any other ideas that i can add that global message from Spring Bean to `FacesContext` without `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage()`?

Comment: There is no `FacesContext` as you are running outside of the JSF servlet. What isn't there cannot be accessed. Also `@ManagedProperty` in a spring bean will do nothing as `@ManagedProperty` is to be used in JSF managed beans NOT spring managed beans.

Comment: I know: "Because this class is not in JSF lifecycle, FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() returns null". Than what is the solution for returning message from Spring Security to the JSF servlet?

Comment: Find some intermediate solution. Store them in the session ad before rendering the page set them as faces messages (or something alike).

Comment: Even if you're using JSF for your application, this form completely gets rid of the JSF lifecycle. You're basically performing a POST against a non-JSF endpoint. So, as Deinum says, you could write some kind of hack as using the session scope, for example. Other alternative might be not to use primefaces in your login page and use javascript to display the message from the response.

Comment: Just use Spring way to add a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i solved this. Thanks @M.Delinum and @Xtreme Biker for your suggestions. I injected message into HttpSession and get it from http scope. Here is final code:

```
@Component
public class LoginFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginFailureHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.info("Login failed: " + httpServletRequest.getParameter("j_username"), e);
        HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.setAttribute("loginFailMessage", "Login is failed");
        }
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/timsgui/login.jsf?error=true");
    }
}
```

```
<h:outputText value="#{sessionScope['loginFailMessage']}" rendered="#{not empty sessionScope['loginFailMessage']}" styleClass="highlight"/>
```